Apple ARKit and Occlusion: Coarse boundaries
I'm trying to virtually replace the ground floor of a room with a different material. I started with a relative simple approach:
configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
to detect horizontal planes,
arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
to detect the floor and not replacing any other horizontal planes.
The shape of the detected plane is not constant. I'm not trying to fit the detected floor surface with a polygonial plane, but use a rectangular plane bigger than the real floors surface for two reasons:
1.) The resolution of the PBR materials' texture has to be adopted to the changing dimensions, and I haven't found a way to fit the texture to a polygonial plane.
2.) Even a polygonial plane does not follow precisely to the visible boundaries of the floor.
Thus, without occlusion, the plane covers both furniture and walls. With scene understanding, occlusion in general (arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)) works pretty well, but now I have the problems already described by Andy Jazz in 2020:
1.) Transition areas between furniture and floor are relatively coarse; thin structures like table legs disappear
2.) The transition zone is blurred. It looks like having ground fog in the living room.
Two pictures to illustrated the problem:


By having a look at the triangulation the iPhone pro does, you can see directly that the mesh is just way to coarse:

Closely approaching thin structures helps a bit for the moment; but even then, the mesh is not fine enough, and as the triangulation is constantly updated, moving away from the structure coarses the local mesh again immediately.

I understand that the blurring of the boundaries is done to smooth the edges of the triangles, but its of limited use in my case.
It would be good to have a chance to influence the resolution of the mesh and do local refinement in the transition zones. Is there a possibility to do so?
Thanks in advance for your help!

About Scene Reconstruction, Occlusion and MeshAnchor.Geometry
As these problems were in 2020, they remain the same to this day. Perhaps the quality of scene reconstruction has improved a little in visionOS, thanks to a larger number of sensors working as one team, but in general, the notorious problems have not gone away. Nevertheless, RealityKit engineers were beginning to make attempts to change this situation. So far, little has been done in this direction, but the vector of changes has been chosen correctly.
Currently, the only available solution which helps a developer produce a static mesh from a dynamic one, being generated with LiDAR in RealityKit app, is to use a .generateStaticMesh(from:) asynchronous type method. However, this method returns a low-poly ShapeResource object, that is only suitable for usage on physics engine in static mode (not even dynamic or kinematic mode) and for collisions.
if let shape = try? await ShapeResource.generateStaticMesh(from: meshRsrc) {

    await MainActor.run {

        let entity = Entity()
        let collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shape])
        entity.components.set(collision)

        let physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(massProperties: .default,
                                                     material: nil, 
                                                         mode: .static)
        entity.components.set(physicsBody)
    }
}

